# Newtons Law of Cooling Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics

We have two differential equations, 
$$\begin{cases} {dT\over dt} = -\alpha(T-B)\\ {dB\over dt} = -\beta(B-T)\end{cases}$$

If $T(0) = 7$ and $B(0) =3$, determine the equilibrium temperature of the system. Is the equilibrium temperature closer to the initial $T$ or initial $B$ value? Explain why this makes sense.

If $t(0) = T(o)$ and $B(0) =B(o)$ determine the eq. temperatur eof the system.

Previously we performed an eigenvalue analysis (assuming $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=2$) to determine the systems behavior. However, Im confused how to do the question asked above, do we just plug the values of those into our system and that's the answer?

Comment: should it be $\frac{dT}{dt} = -\alpha (T-B) $ instead of $-\alpha (T-\beta)$  ?

Comment: Presumably the equilibrium corresponds to a stable fixed point of the system.

Comment: I apologize, I couldnt use the code to make it nicely but ,I did write DT/dt! So yeah, it is that. :)

Comment: it's the B instead of the $\beta$ that is important

Comment: Oh, I see now. I fixed it, sorry!

Comment: What's $T(o)$? What's $t(0)$? What's $B(o)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the general solution to 
$x'=Mx$ is $x=C_1 e^{\lambda _1 t} v_1 + C_2 e^{\lambda _2 t} v_2$

where the lambdas and vs are eigenvalues and eigenvectors of M and the Cs are constants.

in your case $M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} -\alpha & \alpha \\ \beta & -\beta \end{array}\right) $

which has $\lambda_1 = 0, v_1 =\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right) $  and $\lambda_2 = -(\alpha+\beta), v_2 =\left(\begin{array}{c} -\alpha \\ \beta \end{array}\right) $

so your solution is

$\left(\begin{array}{c} T \\ B \end{array}\right)=C_1 \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right) + C_2 e^{-(\alpha+\beta) t} \left(\begin{array}{c} -\alpha \\ \beta \end{array}\right)$

use the initial conditions to solve for the constants, $C_1$ will be the final temperature.

Comment: You gave us a pretty good idea on what to do, even helping us solve the parts afterwards! thank you very much for your help sir, very much appreciated! There might be an extra part which is confusing me, but ill post that when I get there. Thank you again! :)